# Fasten query elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a query on elasticsearch but I'm suprise by the fact that the response is very slow.

```
request = {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{"match": {"user.id": self.id}}]
                }
            },
            "sort": [
                {"created_at": {"order": "asc"}}
            ]
        }
```

The query take three seconds and a half (3.5s) to have a response. I'm working in local so the problem can't come from a network issue.

How can I improve the speed of my query knowing that the query hit an index containing 40 millions documents?

Comment: Is it faster without the sort? What is the spec of your local machine?

Comment: Yeah but barely (3s)
Intel core i3
Memory 7.5 GiB
Hard drive 516 GB

Comment: what is your index data-size ? how much RAM allocated to ES ?

Comment: @Rahul The index size is 159.5GB and the RAM allocated is 2GB

Comment: Well, there could be multiple reasons for slow response times : total number of segments, current indexing rate, other cpu-intensive processes running on the same machine, ongoing merge process in elasticsearch, lack of free memory, frequency of full GC, fieldData cache size in heap etc are some of them. You need to check each of them to get some hint.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing if my query is optimal or if I can improved it

Comment: I have explained in the answer, how you can optimize your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you are using the default settings, you are using the Standard Analyzer

The [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) before actually querying, will apply the same standard analyzer to the search term. It will also calculate the score of the matching documents which will also have some impact on the query performance.

The [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) does not apply any analyzers to the search term, so will only look for that exact term in the inverted index.

Now, whether the scoring is computed or not, depends on the [query-filter-context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)

**Query context**

> A query clause used in query context answers the question “How well
>   does this document match this query clause?” Besides deciding whether
>   or not the document matches, the query clause also calculates a _score
>   representing how well the document matches, relative to other
>   documents.

**Filter context**

> In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated.
>
> Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch,
>   to speed up performance.

You may create your query as described below :

```
GET _search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match_all": {}}
      ],
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "user.id": <YOUR_ID_PARAM> }}, 
      ]
    },
    "sort" :{.....}
  }
}
```

Comment: @mel Did you see any improvement in response time ?